# DB2 conditionally firing triggers

Tags: triggers, db2

I want to conditionally disabling triggers in DB2 by using global variable only for the current session, for example in a trigger like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_headcount 
   AFTER INSERT ON employees
   FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL 
   UPDATE hr_stats 
   SET headcount = headcount + 1;
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may run it as is to check.

```
-- This value (TRUE) will be inherited by every session
CREATE VARIABLE GV_EMPLOYEE_TRIG_ENABLED BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE;
GRANT READ ON VARIABLE GV_EMPLOYEE_TRIG_ENABLED TO PUBLIC;
-- Don't forget to allow the corresponding user to change the variable's value
-- GRANT WRITE ON VARIABLE GV_EMPLOYEE_TRIG_ENABLED TO ...;
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES (ID INT);
CREATE TABLE HR_STATS (HEADCOUNT INT);
INSERT INTO HR_STATS (HEADCOUNT) VALUES 0;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_headcount 
   AFTER INSERT ON employees
   FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL 
   WHEN (GV_EMPLOYEE_TRIG_ENABLED)
   UPDATE hr_stats 
   SET headcount = headcount + 1;

-- Trigger works in every session
-- if you don't touch the variable
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES VALUES 1;
SELECT * FROM HR_STATS;
```

| HEADCOUNT |
| --- |
| 1 |

```
-- Affects the current session only,
-- since every session has its own value of a variable
SET GV_EMPLOYEE_TRIG_ENABLED = FALSE;
-- Trigger doesn't work
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES VALUES 1;
SELECT * FROM HR_STATS;
```

| HEADCOUNT |
| --- |
| 1 |

[dbfiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/1REbs0w3)

Comment: Ok thx, will try it. But for normal insert statements, is it possible to deactivate comstraints Checks?

Comment: You may use [Informational constraints](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=constraints-informational). That is, set them as not enforced. The effect would be the same as your SET INTEGRITY IMMEDIATE UNCHECKED use after LOAD.

Comment: @mastermistik If this answer addresses your question, then please, mark it as accepted. The same is for your other questions.